# Context Problem in Blender 2.80 python module

Tags: python, scripting, operator, versions

I run Blender 2.80 as python module (for running on a server with Django), so there is no gui. 
Apparently passing the correct context doesn't seem to work for me in this case.
I have tried many suggested implementations to override context (a lot were for Blender 2.7), but i still get context errors for most operators
For example the line: `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` 
with or without     `...(override, ...`

produces the error

> bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect

and I cannot search through the contexts until for example the correct area is found:

```
for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        v3d = area.spaces[0]
        rv3d = v3d.region_3d
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                break            

override = {
    'scene'            : bpy.context.scene,
    'region'           : region,
    'area'             : area,
    'space'            : v3d
}
```

as this will produce the error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'screen'

When running the following Code:

```
print(bpy.context.window)
print(bpy.context.mode)
print(bpy.context.area)
print(bpy.context.region)
print(bpy.context.scene)
```

the output I get is:

```
None 
OBJECT 
None 
None 
<bpy_struct, Scene("Scene")>
```

So maybe there is no fully set context to begin with? Could it be an option to make a new context?

The problem occurs even when i have a .py (with only some other Django methods) where i use `import bpy` at the start of the file and do `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` in an if statement that is activated by django at the program startup.

However this code example works normally and exports a .stl file with a rounded cube:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects["Cube"], do_unlink=True)
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
myObj = bpy.context.object
myObj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = myObj
myObj.location = ( 0, 1, 1)
myObj.scale = ( 1/2, 1/2, 1/2)
mySubsurfMod = myObj.modifiers.new(myObj.name, 'SUBSURF')
mySubsurfMod.levels = 4
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath="myExportSTL.stl")
```

Does someone know how to make override context work in blender 2.80?
Or maybe at least a good resource for deep level commands to avoid operators? Or is there maybe even a way to see the deep level commands which are accessed by the operators (similar to the info screen) in blender?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please provide some example of how you are running this from command line, where and how you are overriding context.

Comment: I now added some additional information and did some corrections.

Comment: Expect `context.window, context.screen` etc to be `None` in headless mode. Where are you getting the error for edit mode change operator?  Recommend using `myObj = context.object`  A new cube may not always have the name "Cube"

Comment: (In the python script which is activated by a button in HTML and Django) i basically only have `import bpy` and then `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')`. This is enough to trigger the context error. I see the error in the Django interface and in the command window, which is running the Django server.

Comment: How about you actually clarify this. Post a script with the operator that doesn't work. Post the command line you are using to call it. I  Don't use Django, however do have `bpy` as a python module on ubuntu.  [No problems calling  operator from python shell](http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=0e3005dbb111e449a171b286e70d353e)

Comment: Thank you batFinger!! By trying your python shell idea i have found a solution to the Problem: 
I found that in the command window, when I write what you did:
`>>python >>import bpy >>bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` it works normally and prints `{'FINISHED'}`
So then i went on to search the cause of the error in where exactly i run my script...

Comment: ...It seems, that the precise location where i do the `import bpy` is very important.
My error was that I put `import bpy` at the top of my .py (prior to some Django getUserInput function). 
**Therefore i strongly reccomend to others working in Django or other python environments
to always use `import bpy` DIRECTLY before your blender scripting.**
I have now also tried to run a more advanced script and it works!

Comment: Somehow i did not expect a error of this nature, as the make rounded cube script i posted worked normally.
@batFinger I suggest you formulate this as an answer like: 
_Expect context.window, context.screen etc to be None in headless mode. Make sure you do_ `import bpy` _DIRECTLY before your blender scripting. You might also try to run ...(Your Shell Picture)... in your Python shell to see if this works normally._
Then i can accept it as answer.

Comment: Shamelessly took you up on the offer. Please feel free to [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/144459/edit) in any other info that may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some things to check and look out for.**

- Expect `context.window, context.screen` etc to be `None` in headless
  mode.
- If an operator works in the python console in blender then chances
  are it needs no special window, screen or region for context.  AFAIK
  the edit mode toggle operator only needs an editable object active.
- Check the `bpy` module works in your python shell 
  [image]
- Recommend using `myObj = context.object` A new cube may not always have
  the name "Cube" *eg Cube in another language*
- The space member of context is `context.space_data` or from the area as `area.spaces.active`.

And the answer was, [as supplied by the OP](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144233/context-problem-in-blender-2-80-python-module#comment246491_144233)

> ...It seems, that the precise location where i do the `import bpy` is
>   very important. My error was that I put `import bpy` at the top of my
>   .py (prior to some Django `getUserInput` function). Therefore i strongly
>   recommend to others working in Django or other python environments to
>   always use `import bpy` **DIRECTLY** before your blender scripting. I have
>   now also tried to run a more advanced script and it works!

Comment: Interesting! I appreciate the answer, but my script still doesn't work even when moving import bpy to directly before the first call to bpy.